# I can't figure out why a link seems to be returning false when clicked - will Console help?

Tags: javascript, console

I have a pop-up window in a web app that allows you to edit details of a job. You can also click a link to cancel/delete that job. But when I click that link right now after making some edits to it, nothing happens.

It behaves as if javascript was targeting it with "return: false;" so it does nothing. The URL is correct. How can I check if there is JS intercepting my click event, and where it's doing that? Can Console do that? I'm not sure how if so.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note - you could change the id & class of the element, and see if it still doesn't work. If something was intercepting it, it would probably be using getElementById to assign a particular function.

Comment: It's a lot of jQuery so it could be inherited from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In firebug you can debug your javascript code with:

```
console.log('text and '+variables);
```

You can click the console tab in firebug and see values. you can add a console.log line within your click handler to see if it's even getting inside the handler.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the opposite problem. I dont know where the JS block that is intercepting my HTML link is! Was hoping for a location like Firebug does for CSS with "Inspect Element"

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could post some code or a link.

Answer (score 1):

chrome's developer tools will list all handlers registered for an event on an element. i don't know of any other tools that provide this info.

Comment: OK I need to check into how to access that specific info in the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) is an invaluable tool for helping you debug javascript / coding javascript applications. I would suggest installing it to see what your error is etc.

Alternatively, Firefox has an Error Console, which you can view Javascript errors as well.

Comment: I do not see him mentioning that there was not an error and gathering from the "error" tag, I took it there was an error :)

Comment: I use Firebug about 8 hours a day! It's not an official error, but the click is being intercepted and returned false and I was wondering if the Console could tell me where that JS is?